# How to make an api.ai bot (Python) and integrate it in twilio?

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es

I need to integrate my api.ai (python) bot with webhooks enabled in Twilio. I am unable to find any examples regarding it. On api.ai forum, i have found example regarding twilio integration but that wasn't  with webhooks.
can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Hi, Azka, did you take a look at https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-twilio-bot ?

Comment: Yes i did. I am able to return messages through api.ai. But whenever i use webhooks, it doesn't return any message.Does it require text message to be sent as an object as we do while sending it to facebook?

Comment: `result.fulfillment.speech` field should be fulfilled using your webhook, for details please take a look at docs here https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook#section-format-of-response-from-the-service

Comment: Maybe you could add some logs to the question?